# Deleting all lines that they have a specific characters between two positions in file in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command, centos7

I want to create a script file to do these things:

1. I'll give this script a file name and the script will delete all lines that have a specific character between two positions, for example: the script must delete all lines that have "mz" between 1st and 7th character only, otherwise will do nothing.
2. Enhance this script to read the word and positions as an input from the user where the positions should be numbers, otherwise, the script should halt with an error message.

I've used

```
sed -i '/mz/d' filename
```

but this command will delete all lines that have mz whatever the positions are.
Thank you

Edit:
Test.txt

1- hello guys,mz how are you? I hope you are doing fine.

2- I mz hope to do this thing correctly.

3- hi Mz, I hope to do this thing together.

this is a sample txt file that has 3 lines, first line will not be deleted because mz position isn't between 3th and 7th positions.
the second line will be deleted because mz in the right positions.
the third line will also deleted
Note: I can use anythings, I'm not forced to use sed command

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Does it have to use `sed`? I think this is difficult with just a basic or extended regexp.

Comment: I would use a `while read -r line` loop instead. Use a bash parameter expansion operator to extract characters between the two positions. Check whether that variable matches wildcard `*mz*`. If not, it prints the line.

Comment: Parameter expansion: `${var:startindex:length}`

Comment: `perl -ne 'print unless substr($_,0,7) =~ m/mz/' input`

Comment: @Barmar, in the first question, I must give it just the filename and it'll delete all lines that contain mz between 3th and 10th positions (character). Then I must give the script the word and the two positions.

Comment: @BasemAlsalahi All that is very clear in the question.

Comment: @Barmar I'm sorry to bother you, but can you tell me how to use a while loop with Parameter expansion, I mean how the script will look like? thanks alot

Comment: What part don't you understand? There's nothing special about using parameter expansion inside a while loop.

Comment: The loop is like `while read -r line; do ...; done < filename`

Comment: Parameter expansion is `substring=${line:0:7}`

Comment: I'm not sure how much more I can help you without just doing your entire homework for you.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, I've used a while loop with Parameter expansion, also I've used if statement to test the condition and execute sed to delete these lines.. thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: If you figured it out, you can post it as a solution in the Answers section.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v fst=$1 -v trm="$2" -v lst="$3" '{ astr=substr($0,fst,lst);if (match(astr,trm) ) { next } }1' filename
```

Using awk, pass the letter count as variable cnt set from the first passed script parameter. Set search term as variable trm set from the second passed parameter. Then create a variable astr which represents the first characters specified by cnt and utilising awk's substr function. Use this astr variable and attempt to match against the passed trm variable. If it matches, skip to the next line otherwise print with short hand 1.

Comment: thank you very match, but how to specify the first and last position, I mean what if I need the search term between 4th and 10th positions?.. and if it was so I need to delete these lines, otherwise skip and do nothing...

Comment: You can add the first position as an additional parameter. I have amended the answer with a new variables fst and lst instead of cnt..

Answer (score 0):

When `mz` is in the first 7 positions, at most 5 characters are in front of `mz`.

```
sed -ir '/^.{0,5}mz/d' file
```